# using jQuery .animate for search box animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, jquery-ui

Respected ppl ....

Im working on the search component of my app ...

http://jsfiddle.net/SkyKOG/K8utq/24/

```
input{
    display:none;
    width:0px;
    color:#999;
}
```

Initially i just had a searchbox so the current functions are for that .... but now the requirement is as such ...

The text box should be hidden and should appear then expand on click on the search icon ... (tried doing display:none and on click bud didnt work for me) ...

Thanks very much ...

Regards

Comment: working fine??whats to be done?

Comment: hide but when??should appear but when?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming this is what you want..

use click event of icon to toggle the textbox...with rest of your code

```
 $('#searchinout').find('i').click(function(){
    $('#expandbox').toggle('slow');
});
```

and this to your CSS

```
#expandbox{
  display:none;
}
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/K8utq/39/)

Comment: weclome... glad it helped...:).. happy coding

Comment: Thanks ... just one thing ... as a better ux ... can you please help in hiding the textbox when i click anywhere apart from the textbox ... like the boxy or anywhere ... currnetly it hides on the icon .... http://jsfiddle.net/SkyKOG/K8utq/44/

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/K8utq/53/ .. i am checing the class and id here.. so be careful

Comment: that is because i am using body an jsfiddle uses iframe ... anyways try with document instead of body... http://jsfiddle.net/K8utq/55/ here you go

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//hide the textbox on document ready
$("#txtSearch").hide();

//make it visble on search icon click
$(".Search").click(function () {
$("#txtSearch").show();
});

});
```

or you can set the display property of textbox to none and set it to bloock on icon click() event.

Answer (score 1):

you may try the code below.

```
input{
    width:0px;
    color:#999;
    opacity:0;
}

var inputWdith = '200px';
var inputWdithReturn = '0px';   

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.icon-search').click(function(){
    //animate the box
    $('#expandbox').animate({
      width: inputWdith,
      opacity: 1
    }, 800 )
    $('#expandbox').focus();
  }); 

  $('#expandbox').blur(function(){
    $(this).animate({
      width: inputWdithReturn,
      opacity: 0
    }, 800 )

  });
});
```

Comment: Hey this fixes the body problem too :) ... but clicking on the icon when second time (after open) causes the input to close and open again ...if you can fix that ...ill mark this as the best UX answer ....

Comment: try this code to fix the issue:

  `$('.icon-search').click(function(){
     //animate the box
      if($('#expandbox').css('width')==inputWdithReturn){
        $('#expandbox').animate({
         width: inputWdith,
         opacity: 1
         }, 800 );
         $('#expandbox').focus();
      }
  });`